# How do I find where I rendered my images?

Tags: rendering, image, video

I rendered my animation as an image sequence. I can't find the images so I can render them into a video. How do I find them so I can make them an image strip?

Comment: Go into the Render settings tab, under the *output* panel there is a path where Blender outputs your renders by default. You are well advised to set it up before rendering any animations